# Return true from Settimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, callback, settimeout

I know there are stacks of ways this `could` be possible.  And I also understand settimeout is async and "true" can't easily be returned, without promises.

But I'm struggling to return true from this function, with promises.

What is the best way I can return true, from this snippet of code?  (I want to return true, IF an element exists).

I need to be able to specificially return `true`.

Or is there another way I can achieve this.  Waiting for a DOM element to exist on a page and return `true` when it does?

```js
function waitForElement(className, callBack){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        window.setTimeout(function(resolve){
            var element = document.querySelector(className);
            if(element) {
                callBack(className, element);
                console.log("Element exists")
            } else {
                waitForElement(className, callBack);
                console.log("Wait...")
            }
        },1000)
    });
};

waitForElement(".helping-hand-sliding-data h2",function(){
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better not to mix promises and callbacks. Just invoke `resolve(element)` once it's ready and `await` the whole thing:

```js
function waitForElement(className) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        function wait() {
            let element = document.querySelector(className);
            if (element) {
                resolve(element)
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(wait, 500)
                console.log("Wait...")
            }
        }
        wait()
    });
}

setTimeout(function() {
    let fake = document.createElement('div')
    fake.className = 'helping-hand-sliding-data'
    document.body.appendChild(fake)
}, 2000)


async function main() {
    let element = await waitForElement(".helping-hand-sliding-data");
    console.log('FOUND!', element)
}

main()
```

Comment: Thank you @georg!  I don't think this returns "true" though.  I can see a promise is returned:



Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: @ReenaVerma The `waitForElement()` promise fulfills with the element. The `main()` promise fulfills with `undefined`. At no point you need the value `true`.

Comment: You cannot return anything from an async function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: ok thank you.  The application I'm using is specifically looking for a "return true/or something" rather than a promise.  I wondered if there was another way I could achieve this?

Comment: If you have a strictly synchronous flow, there's no way you can integrate an async action into it. Javascript can't just stop running and wait for something.